# How to change directory of a file in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, virtual-machine

I have python file in by ubuntu virtual machine's home directory. Is there any way I can move it to another directory instead of copying the entire code and then making a file in the directory and then pasting and saving it as a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the copy (cp) command?

```
cp <file_to_copy> <location_to_copy_to>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very silly question.

Just copy/cut the file and move it to the required directory. No need to copy the code and the creating a new file in another directory you can  do this manually ( by right clicking, cut ,paste) or via terminal by just typing `mv [Path of file] [The destination` or `cp [Path of file] [Destination]`